# Pulling out XML attribute information in Scala

Tags: xml, scala

I'm trying to iterate over all the attributes in a `scala.xml.Elem` and get the namespace, attribute name and value as a String. I've found it a bit hard going to be honest; is there a better way to do it than:

```
 elem.attributes map { md => (md.getNamespace(elem), md.key, md.value(0).text) }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way to do this. If you need to extract data from MetaData objects a lot, you could [write your own extractor](http://daily-scala.blogspot.com/2009/09/extractors-1.html) to get nicer syntax.

Comment: Fair enough! The above is not exactly verbose, of course, but it just seemed unnecessarily painful to discover. I have hopes for [anti-xml](https://github.com/paulp/anti-xml), but they don't appear to have namespace support yet.